# While talking about a limited number

Tags: phrase-meaning

While talking about a limited number of a car model can I say sentence below?

> This car was produced in limited number of nineteen.

I am trying to say the total number of a car model is limited to nineteen units. Does sentence describe this situation? Should I use different word instead of “number”.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, yes what you have written is understandable, though not quite standard usage.

More common would be "The car was produced in a limited edition of nineteen" or "The car was produced in a limited production run of just nineteen"

To use the word 'number' specifically, you would want to say use the plural, something like: "The car was produced in limited numbers - just nineteen in total"

Comment: I agree that what OP wrote is "understandable". But OP should be aware that it's nowhere near syntactically valid - it's just a "word salad" that we can probably guess the intended meaning of.

Comment: Harsh. One word and one pluralisation away from normal usage is better than most UK politicians can manage.

Comment: You think? Personally, I think Boris Johnson is an amazingly competent speaker. He must be good if he can convince half the population that he doesn't know how to talk properly! :) Besides, politics is the art of saying words that don't have clearly defined meanings, in hopes that multiple potential voters with *different* opinions might all believe that whatever you're saying is the same as whatever they happen to think.

Answer (score 2):

A "[limited run](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/limited-run)" is frequently used in this sort of sentence. Link goes to Collins English Dictionary, which includes several examples of this phrase in the news. In your sentence, it would be used like this:

> This car was produced in a limited run of nineteen [units].